# Meaning of "croquant" when used figuratively

Tags: figure-de-style, langage-informel

George Brassens wrote many songs in which he talks about "croquantes et croquants", as if speaking of a particular kind of people.

For instance:

> Les croquants, ça les attriste, ça
>   Les étonne, les étonne
>   Qu'une fille, une fille belle comme ça
>   S'abandonne, s'abandonne
>   Au premier ostrogoth venu
>   Les croquants, ça tombe des nues

Who are these people?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an old derogatory word similar to "peasant".

In modern French, *péquenot* (redneck) might be used with a similar meaning.

In this song, *croquants* is definitely used to name peasants, and in this case relatively healthy and avaricious ones, as shows this verse:

> Les croquants vont en ville, à cheval sur leurs sous

See the [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/croquant/1)

Answer (score 3):

Although [croquant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croquant_rebellions) has a very definite meaning, Brassens is using the the metaphor with a rhetorical strategy to designate middle class persons, typically with reference to its perceived materialistic values or conventional attitudes.

Comment: +1 for referring to the original meaning, and for raising the point that Brassens develops a vocabulary on social and moral issues that is entirely his own. A Brassens concordancer (I don't think there is one...) would point to many uses of croquant, as the OP notes, and always with that meaning - rural, middle class, materialistic, conservative, awful.